# find the fixed points of $\dot{\theta} = \omega - a\sin{\theta}$ for $a > \omega $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, fixed-points

I am working through an example in Strogatz's dynamical systems book (second edition, example 4.3.1, page 99). and came across something in one of his examples. The problem is to find the fixed points in the flow of a system given below and then find the stability at both of the fixed points.

The equation is given by:

$$
\dot{\theta} = \omega - a\sin{\theta} \
$$

Now to find the fixed points in the flow I would set $\dot{\theta} = 0$, and solve for $\theta$, so:

$$
0 = \omega - a\sin{\theta} \\
sin{\theta}^* = \frac{\omega}{a}\\
$$

But the book also gives an additional solution:

$$
\cos{\theta}^* = \pm \sqrt{1 - (\omega/a)^2}
$$

The question is how did Strogatz arrive at this second solution for $\cos{\theta}^*$? From the plot of the system it is obvious that there are 2 fixed points in the domain of the equation, but I was not sure how he arrived at this second fixed point.  Any suggestions would help. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you said *which* example in the book you are referring to. (Example number? Page number? Which edition of the book?)

Comment: I added the page info as you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixed points are given by the condition
$$
\sin \theta^* = \omega/a
,
$$
nothing else. (And this equation has two solution per period of the sine function, if $\omega<a$.)

The second formula,
$$
\cos \theta^* = \pm \sqrt{1-(\omega/a)^2}
$$
is not an additional solution, but just a consequence of the identity
$$
\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1
.
$$
(He needs that formula in order to evaluate $f'(\theta^*)$ just below.)

Comment: I fixed the $a$ issue. You are right, I mistakenly looked at the formula for the stability analysis of that root, which has a similar formula. You can remove that comment from your post if you like.

Comment: Okay this is great. Yes, this seems to make a lot more sense. Strogatz did not explain those steps, so I was just trying to make sure I understood the logic. Thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome!